# Martial arts club event in North Point

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I won several times the martial arts club event in North Point but it seems that nothing special happens. The indicator continues to be present on the map and I can repeat it continuously. Is it so by design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play each martial arts club event as many times as you wish. I think it was there for levelling up.